# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.find(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; while using PhantomJS 2.1.1 with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

OS - Windows 7

PhantomJS version - 2.1.1

Selenium - 3.8.1(selenium-server).

JDK - 152.

I'm trying to run simple test, using PhantomJS:

1) initializing the driver:

```
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path","src\\main\\resources\\phantomjs.exe");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```

2) any test, let it be verifying text "welcome" on en.wikipedia.org:

```
driver.get("http://en.wikipedia.org");
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Welcome')]")).isDisplayed());
```

3) Running test, but receiving errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.find(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.findPhantomJS(PhantomJSDriverService.java:232)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:94)
```

Googling showed, that such troubles occur time to time (non-compatible selenium/PhantomJS).
Question: is there any workaround for making last selenium(s) and 2.1.1 PhantomJS good friends?

note: any other driver works fine (edge, chrome, ff).

Comment: Can you update the Question with your Selenium/WebDriver/Browser versions along with your code trials?

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing says it all :

```
NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.find(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

### Class **`NoSuchMethodError`**

[**`NoSuchMethodError`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) extends [**`IncompatibleClassChangeError`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/IncompatibleClassChangeError.html) and as per the *Java Docs* it is thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler and this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

### Solution

Perform the following steps :

- Update your **`JDK`** to the most recent versions (**`Java 8 Update 151`**)
- Clean up the **`Project Space`** from the IDE.
- Run **`CCleaner`** tool to wipe off all the OS system chores.
- Take a **`System Reboot`**
- Add only **Selenium-Java Clients v3.8.1** jar.
- As you are using *PhantomJSDriver (GhostDriver)* you need to add the following *Maven Dependency* :

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
      <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- You need to update the line **`System.setProperty`** with the absolute path of the **`phantomjs`** binary as follows :

  ```
  File path=new File("C:\\path\\\to\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
  System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path",path.getAbsolutePath());
  WebDriver driver= new PhantomJSDriver();
  driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in/");
  ```
- Execute your **`Test`**

Comment: Works like a charm with 1.4.0, thanks man! Just note: not sure why, but on my machine I got troubles with updating from com.github.detro.   From com.codeborne  -  no issues.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a different scenario where the same exception can be faced.

While using Eclipse below code was working :

```
File file = new File("C://phantomjs.exe");
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```

While using Intellij, the same above code was throwing the error as mentioned in the question.

But the below worked with the Intellij :

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C:\\phantomjs.exe");

WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

*Note:Dont forget to change the exe path.*