# Chrome options - Selenium 3.10 - NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, guava

Selenium - 3.10.0 Guava used as -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Excluded all other guava dependencies.

How can this exception be resolved?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()Ljava/util/stream/Collector; 
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.asMap(ChromeOptions.java:306) 
    at org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities.merge(MutableCapabilities.java:74) 
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities.merge(DesiredCapabilities.java:107)     
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities.merge(DesiredCapabilities.java:33) 
    at org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities.setCapability(MutableCapabilities.java:97)
```

> net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:jar:1.3.1:compile
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.4.1:compile
>   com.hynnet:oracle-driver-ojdbc6:jar:12.1.0.1:compile
>   com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.8:compile
>   xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
>   org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
>   org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:1.2.1:compile
>   junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile 
>   org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
>   org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:compile 
>   org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:compile
>   org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.6.2:compile
>   org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19:compile 
>   org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.2:compile 
>   org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.2:compile 
>   org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.2:compile
>   org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.6.2:compile 
>   org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.6.2:compile
>   org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:compile
>   info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.2.5:compile 
>   info.cukes:cucumber-core:jar:1.2.5:compile 
>   info.cukes:cucumber-html:jar:0.2.3:compile 
>   info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:jar:1.0.5:compile 
>   info.cukes:gherkin:jar:2.12.2:compile
>   info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.5:compile
>   org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.3:compile
>   com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.0:compile
>   com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans:yamlbeans:jar:1.11:compile
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.4:compile
>   org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.8.2:compile
>   org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.8.2:compile
>   log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
>   org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
>   commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
>   org.quickfixj:quickfixj-core:jar:1.6.4:compile 
>   org.apache.mina:mina-core:jar:2.0.16:compile
>   javax.jms:jms:jar:1.2:compile
>   net.sf.expectit:expectit-core:jar:0.8.2:compile
>   com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.54:compile 
>   commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile 
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:jar:4.5.3:compile 
>   org.apache.wink:wink-json4j:jar:1.4:compile 
>   org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:jar:5.14.5:compile 
>   com.hp.lft:sdk:jar:14.0.0:compile
>   com.hp.lft:sdk:jar:javadoc:14.0.0:compile
>   com.hp.lft:report:jar:14.0.0:compile
>   com.hp.lft:unittesting:jar:14.0.0:compile
>   com.hp.lft:verifications:jar:14.0.0:compile
>   com.hp.lft:reportbuilder:jar:14.0.0:compile
>   com.hp.lft:common:jar:14.0.0:compile
>   javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0:compile
>   com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.13:compile 
>   com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.13:compile
>   org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.8:compile
>   org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.8:compile 
>   org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.8:compile 
>   org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
>   org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.2.0:compile 
>   org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.2.0:compile 
>   org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.2.0:compile
>   org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.2.0:compile 
>   org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.2.0:compile 
>   org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile 
>   org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.8:compile 
>   org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile 
>   org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile 
>   org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13:compile 
>   org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.13:compile 
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.7.3:compile
>   org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15:compile 
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.4:compile 
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.0:compile 
>   org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.1:compile 
>   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile 
>   com.vimalselvam:cucumber-extentsreport:jar:2.0.1:compile 
>   com.aventstack:extentreports:jar:3.0.6:compile
>   org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.23:compile
>   org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:jar:3.3.0:compile
>   org.mongodb:bson:jar:3.3.0:compile 
>   org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:3.3.0:compile
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2:compile 
>   org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.9.2:compile 
>   com.relevantcodes:extentreports:jar:2.41.0:compile 
>   org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.16:compile
>   commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile 
>   org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile 
>   org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.16:compile
>   org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.16:compile 
>   com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.04:compile 
>   org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:jar:1.3:compile 
>   org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile 
>   stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile  org.ini4j:ini4j:jar:0.5.1:compile 
>   com.monitorjbl:xlsx-streamer:jar:1.2.0:compile 
>   xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile 
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:3.10.0:compile
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:3.10.0:compile
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:3.10.0:compile
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:jar:3.10.0:compile
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:3.10.0:compile
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:3.10.0:compile
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:jar:3.10.0:compile
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:3.10.0:compile
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:3.10.0:compile
>   net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.9:compile
>   org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
>   commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.6:compile
>   com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.9.1:compile 
>   com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.13.0:compile 
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:jar:3.10.0:compile
>   com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.72:compile
>   org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.1:compile
>   commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.6:compile
>   org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
>   net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.24:compile
>   net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.29:compile
>   net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.28:compile
>   net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-htmlunit:jar:2.28:compile
>   net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:jetty-repacked:jar:9.4.7.v20171121:compile
>   org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
>   org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
>   org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
>   org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.8.v20171121:compile
>   org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:htmlunit-driver:jar:2.29.0:compile
>   javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile 
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.7.v20170914:compile
>   xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:compile  xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile 
>   org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:3.10.0:compile 
>   com.google.guava:guava:jar:23.6-jre:compile 
>   com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile 
>   org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.0.0:compile 
>   com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.3:compile 
>   com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile 
>   org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile

Comment: No need to specifically add dependency for guava. It is automatically included in the selenium-java dependency. Search for guava in this selenium-java 3.10.0 pom.

Comment: Update the question with your code trial including the imports

Comment: @DebanjanB - Added all the jars from core framework and additional dependencies. If that's too much of info, I can edit it again with only local dependencies. I have excluded all the selenium/ guava jars from core framework in my pom

Comment: @Grasshopper - I tried - excluding all guava dependencies for selenium 3.10 and adding the RELEASE version. Also, I tried removing the guava dependency I had added. Still it shows error in both cases - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
 at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.asMap(ChromeOptions.java:306)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.find(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; while using PhantomJS 2.1.1 with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743974/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-openqa-selenium-os-commandline-findljava-lang)

Answer (score 1):

Added this explicit dependency to my pom.xml fixed the issue for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>25.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to SO. Can you please add more details on how adding this dependency attempts to solve the main issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error has been resolved for me. ChromeOptions class was referring to some other class containing toImmutableList() method (sdk jar in my case). Had to find out that particular jar by checking the referred jar and excluding it from the pom dependencies. This resolved the issue

Answer (score -1):

In my Gradle project I fixed it by adding this dependency:

```
   compile 'com.google.guava:guava:25.+'
```

Apparently, something else was overriding it until I explicitly set it